# Why isn't this jquery animation rotating like it's supposed to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, rotation, jquery-animate

This .js works perfectly in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djb3T/1/)

```
function animationLoop() {
    $("#ToBeAnimated").css({
        top: ($("#paperTrail").offset().top - parseInt($("#ToBeAnimated").height()) / 2),
        left: ($("#paperTrail").offset().left - parseInt($("#ToBeAnimated").width()) / 2)
    }).rotate(270);
    $("#ToBeAnimated").animate({
        top: $("#paperTrail").offset().top + $("#paperTrail").height() - $("#ToBeAnimated").height() / 2
      }, 1000, function() {
        $(this).animate({
            rotate: "180deg"
        }, function() {
            $("#ToBeAnimated").animate({
                left: $("#paperTrail").offset().left + $("#paperTrail").width() - $("#ToBeAnimated").width() / 2
            }, 1000, function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    rotate: "90deg"
                }, function() {
                    $("#ToBeAnimated").animate({
                        top: $("#paperTrail").offset().top - $("#ToBeAnimated").height() / 2
                    }, 1000, function() {
                        $(this).animate({
                            rotate: "0deg"
                        }, function() {
                            $("#ToBeAnimated").animate({
                                left: $("#ToBeAnimated").width() / 2
                            }, 1000, function() {
                                setTimeout(animationLoop, 1000);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });

            });
        });
    });
}
animationLoop();​
```

But on the actual site the scissor rotation isn't working or is somehow broken... I have inspected it... guessed and checked... researched possible conflicts...But Im stuck! Maybe I am missing something obvious?

Thanks a million for helping!... To see the animation on the live site just click the "Clip It!!!" button at the bottom of the 1st coupon!

[extreme coupon network](http://www.extremecouponnetwork.com/brand-coupons.html)

UPDATE: It's something to do with having multiple instances of the animation on the page... When I look at a page [with one result](http://extremecouponnetwork.com/children-toys.html) it works for me... HOWEVER... I am still unable to make it work with many items on the page (which is what I am really after).... Ideally... Whichever coupon you click on will have the animation appear on it... Currently the animation only works on the 1st coupon... and very shakey

Thanks again!

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djb3T/1/)

Comment: I get a reference error: `ReferenceError: clipIt2 is not defined`. Note that IDs must be unique, after fixing your scope issue, consider using classes instead of IDs. in fact animation will be performed only for the first element with that specific ID.

Comment: Too many `$("#ToBeAnimated")` and `$("#paperTrail")` used. I suggest you to create one variable for this and use that everywhere. It would make it bit more faster.

Comment: Sorry... the clipIt2 is not defined was from me testing with a duplicate function... I removed it... Still have the problems... I will look at classes now though!

Comment: hahahah buddy i think the function name is clipIt not clipIt2 and in js file what is this doing here : `<?php echo $this->item->link; ?>`

Comment: see this : http://www.extremecouponnetwork.com/templates/ja_wall/js/clip.js you have define clipIt function not clipIt2 :P

Comment: It works for me in Firefox, though it's horribly jerky and slow.

Comment: Sorry... That was just me doing some quick testing with a second function called clipIt2... but it didn't work....

So I have changed the id's to classes but am still seeing some problems... Now the scissors animation only moves down & to the right... Instead of completing the square (like before) but just without rotation... One step forward... One step back :-/

THANKS AGAIN FOR HELPING... Any other ideas?

Comment: Oh... good call... It does work in FF (horribly though).... I was using chrome before... which is what I was talking about when I said it only moved down and to the right... hmmmm ???

Comment: well wanna ask you that you want to speed up that scissor? and when done what to do next?

Comment: Aspiring Aqib - Not quite sure what you are asking... But ideally I would like the scissors animation to last about 1.5 seconds TOTAL... For all 4 sides... then when it completes I am going to try and animate the coupon flying somewhere "to be saved"... then refresh the grid... I haven't gotten that far yet however... Still trying to get the darn scissors to look nice across the different browsers :-/ Thanks for helping by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fiddle you are testing with is using jQuery version 1.8.2. On your webpage, however, you are using version 1.7.2. If you change your jQuery version in the fiddle to 1.7.2, you get exactly the same buggy behavior (jerky animation in FF, no rotation in IE or Chrome) as on your page.

Solution: Update the version of jQuery you're using in your project!

Comment: Geeeze....Thank you for pointing that out!... It seems to have helped a little on my actual live site... Meaning the animation in FF and Chrome at least finishes now... BUT nothing like the smoothness of the fiddle?!??! something is still hosing it up... argh... Thanks everyone!

Comment: I HAVE DISCOVERED IT'S SOMETHING TO DO WITH HAVING MULTIPLE ITEMS ON THE PAGE... If you look at a page with only one result it works [Single Result Page](http://extremecouponnetwork.com/children-toys.html)